# iPhone 8+ constant "call failed"

Tags: iphone

I'm with Verizon and my 8+ is constantly dropping my calls with the error "call failed".
I've tried:
toggling airplane mode
restarting the phone
dialed *#31#
checked for Verizon update
cellular data roaming off
voice and data to 3g
date and time to "set automatically"

Any thoughts?

Comment: Contact Verizon and ask them.  They should be able to tell you.

Comment: "Call Failed" is an error that comes from the carrier.  It can be dropped for any reason and the problem could be anywhere from your phone to the other end point.   When you say "constantly" is it every call,  certain number(s), time(s) of the day?  Can you make any calls?

Comment: I used to get that a lot. New SIM fixed it.